# Phonegap Storage & Database data getting lost once you kill the app in iOS platform

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to retain some data in my Phonegap app using [Cordova Storage API](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/storage/sqlresultsetlist/sqlresultsetlist.html).
But everytime when I opened the app after killing it, it returns `2 rows found`after executing SELECT query.

I am using:

- Cordova: 5.2.0
- Cordova iOS platform 3.9.2
- XCode: 7.0.1
- iOS Simulator 9.0

Is there anything wrong in the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");

    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the behaviour that do you want?

Comment: Why not rows persist in the database. How can I store data even after killing the app in cordova. It should keep adding everytime on deviceready event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to lost your data, remove the line:

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
```

because this delete all data when you initialize your app.

Comment: Thanks @Jose. `unique` constraint from the table defination needs to remove as well.